# merging start and end date cycle dates

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg, lead

I have the below table.

```
CUST_ID START_CYCLE END_CYCLE   WORKER  CUST_SUB_ID CUST_SUB_TYPE
101     1/1/2019    1/31/2019   ABC123  134         HIGH_SUB
101     2/1/2019    4/30/2019   ABC123  136         HIGH_SUB
101     5/1/2019    7/31/2019   ABC123  1414        HIGH_SUB
101     8/1/2019    8/30/2019   ABC123  1469        HIGH_SUB
```

I need to merge dates (exclude rows) when the below occurs.

Criteria:

`lead` cust_sub_id `<>` cust_sub_id

`lead` cust_sub_type = cust_sub_type

`lead` cust_id = cust_id

`lead` worker = worker

Final output:

```
CUST_ID START_CYCLE END_CYCLE   WORKER  CUST_SUB_ID         CUST_SUB_TYPE
 101    1/1/2019    8/30/2019   ABC123  134:136:1414:1469   HIGH_SUB
```

SQL:

```
select 
cust_id,
start_cycle,
end_cycle,
worker,
cust_sub_id,
cust_sub_type,
gaps_in_srv,
case
when gaps_in_srv = 'N'
and cust_sub_id <> lead(cust_sub_id) over (partition by cust_id order by start_cycle) 
and cust_id = lead(cust_id) over (partition by cust_id order by start_cycle)
and worker = lead(worker) over (partition by cust_id order by start_cycle)
then 'Y'
else 'N'
end merge_dts,
dense_rank() over (partition by cust_id, cust_sub_id order by start_cycle) rnk_fst_dt,
dense_rank() over (partition by cust_id, cust_sub_id order by start_cycle desc) rnk_lst_dt
from cust_cycle
```

I can use `listagg` to capture the cust_sub_id once I remove the rows but need help removing those rows before I apply the listagg function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this as a gaps-and-islands problem using `lag()` to determine where an "island" starts and a cumulative sum to assign a grouping number to the island:

```
select cust_id, worker, cust_sub_type, min(start_cycle), max(end_cycle),
       listagg(cust_sub_id, ':') within group (order by start_cycle) as cust_sub_ids
from (select cc.*,
             sum(case when prev_ec <> start_cycle - interval '1' day or
                           prev_cst <> cust_sub_type
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by cust_id, worker order by start_cycle) as grp
      from (select cc.*,
                   lag(end_cycle) over (partition by cust_id, worker order by start_cycle) as prev_ec,
                   lag(cust_sub_type) over (partition by cust_id, worker order by start_cycle) as prev_cst
            from cust_cycle cc
           ) cc
      ) cc
group by cust_id, worker, cust_sub_type, worker
```